# Notice: No compatible server to client encryption algorithms found in

Tags: php, encryption, phpseclib

I'm using PHPSecLib for SSH connection through PHP but I have this error :

Notice: No compatible server to client encryption algorithms found in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\nodejs\includes\classes\net\Net\SSH2.php on line 1170

Why ?

Thanks

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: I use the PHP version 5.4.24

Comment: Damn, no clue then sorry. I just know this bug in combination with PHP versions before 5.3.8 which have NO .phar support. No clue, sorry!

Comment: There's at least two separate posts about this error [to be found on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=phpseclib+no+compatible+server+to+client+encryption+algorithms+found&oq=PHPSecLib+%22No+compatible+server+to+client+encryption+algpr&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.8607j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=121&ie=UTF-8). Please check those out and if you can't solve the problem, update the question with all the attempts you have made to resolve the issue. It might also be helpful to look into the source code and check the conditions for this error message

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what i've done, i tried during lot of hours to search into code but nothing..

Comment: Can you post the logs? To get them you can add `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 3);` to the top of your file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [this post](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/340#issuecomment-43088460),

> So phpseclib determines which symmetric key algorithms it can use by seeing which ones are includable. The following links demonstrate how this is done:
>
> https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/efd3b96dc8e378a5155cb42f4869de85f4153135/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L1110
>   https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/efd3b96dc8e378a5155cb42f4869de85f4153135/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L3775
>
> If you're using PHP 5.4 then it's essentially doing `stream_resolve_include_path('Crypt/RC4.php')`. If PHP doesn't think it's includable than it's hard to argue with that.

Could be your `include_path` that's not correctly set as well.