# No compatible server to client encryption algorithms PHP 7

Tags: ssh, php-7, phpseclib, incompatibility

> Notice: No compatible server to client encryption algorithms found in
>   /var/www/.....

Code:

```
<?php

include_once "Net/SSH2.php";

$ssh_con = new Net_SSH2('dom.server.cl');
$ssh_con->login('user', 'pass');

?>
```

Why? Help please!!!

Comment: Can you post your SSH logs? You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` at the top and then doing `echo $ssh_con->getLog();` after `$ssh_con->login()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641948/notice-no-compatible-server-to-client-encryption-algorithms-found-in may answer your question.